# Show that if $\left|G\right|=\left|X\right|$, so there exist a group-action $G\times X\rightarrow X$ which is free and transitive

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

I saw this question in some book and I cannot manage to solve it. I wanted to try first when the order of G is finite, and just number the elements in both X and G let's say like: $$X=\left\{ x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}\right\} ,\ \ G=\left\{ g_{1},\ldots,g_{n}\right\} $$and send a pair $\left(g_{i},x_{j}\right)\mapsto x_{i}$ but it's not really a valid group action.

It feels like I am missing something simple as it just one question that leads to a bigger one later on which I did manage to solve, but somehow I am really stuck here.

Any hint is welcomed, thank you!

Comment: This is just Cayley's Theorem. It doesn't help to assume that $G$ is finite.

Comment: @DerekHolt I tried using it, doing some composition with the subgroup of symmetrics on G but it didn't work well for me, how do I derive it from Cayle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be $\phi:G\to X$ one bijection between the two set, now define the action $G\times X\to X$:$$g.x=g.\phi(h):=\phi(gh). $$
Its well-defined because $h$ its uniquely determined by $x$ $(h=\phi^{-1} (x))$ and satisfy the action property: $$fg.x=fg.\phi(h)=\phi((fg)h)=\phi(f(gh))=$$ $$=f.\phi(gh)=f.g.\phi(h)=f.g.x  $$ Now its easy to verify that this action its transitive and free.

Comment: Ohhh, it really is simple, sadly it didn't come to me. Thank you!